# How do I create a view controller file after creating a new view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am developing a tabbed application.

When I create a new view controller and link it to the tab bar controller, unlike the other two default view controllers, this one has no `viewcontroller.swift` file.

How can I create this file?

I am using Xcode 6 and developing the app in Swift.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Correct, when you drag a view controller object onto your storyboard in order to create a new scene, it doesn't automatically make the new class for you, too.

Having added a new view controller scene to your storyboard, you then have to:

1. Create a `UIViewController` subclass. For example, go to your target's folder in the project navigator panel on the left and then <kbd>control</kbd>-click and choose "New File...". Choose a "Cocoa Touch Class":

   [image: Cocoa Touch Class]

   And then select a unique name for the new view controller subclass:

   [image: UIViewController subclass]
2. Specify this new subclass as the base class for the scene you just added to the storyboard.

   [image]
3. Now hook up any `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` references for this new scene with the new view controller subclass.

Comment: Can you also create just a `.swift` file? Since your `ViewController.swift` will be the file for use in Swift.

Comment: Thanks, I meant that we could choose a `Swift` file from the pop up instead of the `Cocoa Touch Class`, correct?

Comment: Sure, but this does the same thing and adds the necessary `import` statements and sets the base class and gives you the template for a few methods. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that manually, but certainly you can if you want.

Comment: If you're brave, you can actually skip Step #1 and, in Step #2, you can set the Custom Class to one of your _existing_ view controller classes and have that view controller class handle the actions and outlets for both (or however many) scenes you set to that VC. Note that this has a lot of gotchas (starting with the fact that you need to check if an outlet is nil before you use it), and it's liable to introduce a lot of bugs if you try it for a large project, but it's a handy trick for small/toy/example apps.

Comment: Lol. If you see a light at the end of the tunnel, make sure it's not another train headed right for you at high speed. Technically you're right, of course, but OMG, you're just begging for problems, code maintenance headaches, etc.

Answer (score -2):

To add new `ViewController` once you have have an existing `ViewController`, follow below step:

1. Click on background of `Main.storyboard`.
2. Search and select `ViewController` from object library at the
   utility window.
3. Drag and drop it in background to create a new `ViewController`.