# App crashes when code is connected to storyboard

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I've been trying to connect the IBOutlet's to the releasedatepicker, artisttextfield, albumtextfield, saveTapped and cancelTapped in my EditFreshReleaseViewController for a few days now. But whenever I run the app and tap the Edit button, it crashes the app. When I disconnect the IBOutlet's on that ViewController it opens the edit button fine except I'm stuck there because nothing works in that ViewController now.

Any Ideas?

[IBOutlets on EditFreshReleaseViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkP4N.png)

Below is the code for the EditFreshReleaseViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

class EditFreshReleaseViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var artisttextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var albumtextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var releasedatePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    releasedatePicker.minimumDate = Date()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func saveTapped( _ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let artist = artisttextfield.text ?? ""
    let album = albumtextfield.text ?? ""
    let releasedate = releasedatePicker.date

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newRelease = Release_Date(context: context)
    newRelease.artist = artist
    newRelease.album = album
    newRelease.release_date = releasedate as NSDate?
    newRelease.release_dateId = UUID().uuidString

    if let uniqueId = newRelease.release_dateId {
        print("The freshreleaseId is \(uniqueId)")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        let message = "\(artist)'s new album \(album) releases Today!"
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = message
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day],
                                                             from: releasedate)
        dateComponents.hour = 09
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
                                                    repeats: true)
        if let identifier = newRelease.release_dateId {

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                                content: content, trigger: trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not save because of \(error).")
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Added a Release Date!")
    print("Artist: \(newRelease.artist)")
    print("Album: \(newRelease.album)")
    print("Release Date: \(newRelease.release_date)")
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



}
```

Comment: Show the error message, not only in a screenshot. The issue is that you didn't set the class of the ViewController in InterfaceBuilder to `EditFreshReleaseViewController`. It's still a `UIViewController` (default one). So it doesn't know the cancelTapped method.

Comment: Error comes from AppDelegate.Swift file as Thread 1: signal SIGABRT attached to the line class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: But there is a message in the console. That’s the one you should read at least. And I said the reason, you didn’t set the class of the viewcontroller to yourd

Answer (score 0):

Without the error it is hard to figure out the solution, but you can start by making the @IBOutlet weak

```
@IBOutlet weak var artisttextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var albumtextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var releasedatePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

Also sometimes when you copy and paste a UIViewcontroller elements from a different UIViewcontroller the @IBOutlet's lost the references, try cleaning you project, close Xcode, restart everything.

Comment: 2018-10-30 15:53:27.213772-0400 fresh release[7843:2107116] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x12bd00920> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key albumtextfield.'

Comment: I already said it `[<UIViewController 0x12bd00920> `, it's written `UIViewController`, not `EditFreshReleaseViewController`. You didn't set the class of the ViewController in the Storyboard to `EditFreshReleaseViewController`. Last image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589496/1801544