# Xcode: I can't access a view controller for a scene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I open the .swift file for ViewController below, on the left?

I'm ultimately following
[question for how to access text in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234811/how-do-i-access-text-in-uitextfield-from-another-viewcontroller-swift)
but don't know how to open the ViewController to do it.

[image]

Comment: there is no controller named "ViewController", so first set correct one in IB then you should redirect when you pressed right arrow as @Donat Kabashi mentioned

Comment: [This works for me: Add the view controller manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587577/how-do-i-create-a-view-controller-file-after-creating-a-new-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Just press the button at the right inspector.

[image: Button that opens the view controller]

In case you deleted or renamed that view controller, you should rename the class of the respective view controller in storyboard.

Comment: Hmm.  Nothing happens.  The button goes dark, but no swift file on the left file list.

Comment: I learned that I first must manually add a viewcontroller class, then I press that button.